# has_many relationship using FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord, factory-bot

I'm trying to create instance with `has_many` relationship using FactoryGirl factories and fail.
I have two classes: Computers and NetworkCards. Each Computer can have many NetworkCards.

Defined two ActiveRecords:

1.

```
class Computer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :network_cards
end
```

2.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: computer
end
```

Defined the following factories:

1.

```
factory :computer do
  sequence(:name) { |n| "PC_#{n}" }
  transient do
    network_cards_count 1
  end

  after(:create) do |computer|
    create_list(:network_card, evaluator.network_cards_count, computer: computer)
  done
end
```

2.

```
factory :network_card do
  sequence(:name) { |n| "NC_#{n}" }
  sequence(:type) { |n| "TYPE_#{n}" }
end
```

Now, when creating a computer in a RSpec test I get a weird behavior I can't explain.

```
@computer_1 = FactoryGirl.create(:computer)
@computer_1.network_cards.size #Expect 1. Got 0. Why?
@computer_1.reload
@computer_1.network_cards.size # Got 1
```

Any ideas what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 after(:build) do |computer, evaluator|
      computer.network_cards << build_list(:network_card, evaluator.network_cards_count, computer: computer)
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
factory :computer do
  sequence(:name) { |n| "PC_#{n}" }
  transient do
    network_cards_count 1
  end

  after(:create) do |computer, evaluator|
    create_list(:network_card, evaluator.network_cards_count, computer: computer)
    computer.reload #<----- solves the issue
  end
end
```

Comment: Is `evaluator` available if it's not in your block like @Ahmed's answer? I've always specified it.

Comment: @Dan it's a typo. fixed